# Centering image in columns (liquid layout)

Tags: html, center, multiple-columns

My goal is to make each of these images be centered in their respective columns while maintaining the liquid layout. Each of the images should be centered in each column (e.g. one flag per column centered). Any help would be appreciated as this is an assignment. Thanks

HTML and CSS Code

```css
.two { 
      -moz-column-count: 2;
      -webkit-column-count: 2;
      column-count: 2; 
     }
            
            .column1    {
                width:33%;
                float:left;
            }
            
            .column2    {
                width:33%;
                display: inline-block;
            }
            
            .column3    {
                width:33%;
                float:right;
            }
```

```html
<p class="two">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod 
   tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At 
   vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, 
   no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, 
   consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et 
   dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo 
   dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum 
   dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy 
   eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At 
   vero eosle et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea 
            takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
    
       <p class="column1">
     <img src="australia_flag.jpg" height="200" width="300" /> <br>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod 
   tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At 
   vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, 
   no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, 
   consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et 
   dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo 
   dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum 
   dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy 
   eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At 
   vero eosle et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea 
   takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
  </p>
        
        <p class="column2">
     <img src="brazil_flag.jpg" height="200" width="300" /> <br>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod 
   tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At 
   vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, 
   no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, 
   consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et 
   dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo 
   dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum 
   dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy 
   eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At 
   vero eosle et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea 
   takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
  </p>
        
        <p class="column3">
     <img src="china_flag.jpg" height="200" width="300" /> <br>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod 
   tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At 
   vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, 
   no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, 
   consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et 
   dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo 
   dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum 
   dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy 
   eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At 
   vero eosle et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea 
   takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
  </p>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply add this CSS to each image:

```
image {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

The `margin: 0 auto` will automatically set side margins (centering them). The `display: block` is necessary to make the margins work (which don't work on `inline-block`, which images are by default.

See it working on [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jlam55555/s69a6mpx/).

---

Also, avoid using the deprecated `width` and `height` attributes; use CSS `width` and `height` instead.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Didn't realize it was something that simple. Also, I will take your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

there also also several other alternatives as far as I know, as I am not a pro in any way.

you can also try this if it works.

```
image {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}
```

And yes, it is better to use CSS 'width' and 'height' rather than those of deprecated